# understanding add (Erf prob) to the context of the instance declaration errors

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand why the following error arises,

`add (Erf prob) to the context of the instance declaration`

I have a simple instance that is using the `erf` from `Data.Number.Erf`

```
instance (Floating prob) => CDF (Normal prob) where
    cdf dist dp = ( 0.5 * ( 1 + erf ( (x - mu)/ (sqrt $ sigma2 *2) )))
```

but ghc-7.6.3 will complain with the above and a possible fix is to change `instance (Floating prob)` to `instance(Floating prob, Erf prob)` could any one explain why this is needed?
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [Data.Number.Erf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/erf/2.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Number-Erf.html), you see there's

```
class Floating a => Erf a where
  erf :: a -> a
```

This means that the `erf` function is part of the `Erf` class. It's type is `erf :: Erf a => a -> a`. That means that you need to add `Erf a` to the context (bit before the `=>`) of the type of any function that uses it on an `a`, to make sure that `erf` is defined for values of type `a`.

In this case, you've already called that type `prob`, so we need `Erf prob`.

In fact, since `Floating` is a superclass of `Erf`, anything that's an instance of `Erf` must already be an instance of `Floating`, so you don't need to specify that explicitly. This means you could write

```
instance (Erf prob) => CDF (Normal prob) where
   ...
```